# Twitter bootstrap carousel left and right controls

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently the left and right controls on my Bootstrap carousel don't work and I'm trying to figure out why.  The slides don't change.  Any help would be much appreciated.

html code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="images/anaesthesiaexams/cap1.png" alt="Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/anaesthesiaexams/cap2.png" alt="Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/anaesthesiaexams/cap3.png" alt="Flower">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="images/anaesthesiaexams/cap4.png.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey do you have both js and jquery linked?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```